# Efficient algorithm for eliminating nodes in "graph"?

Tags: algorithm, graph-algorithm

Suppose I have a a graph with 2^N - 1 nodes, numbered 1 to 2^N - 1. Node i "depends on" node j if all the bits in the binary representation of j that are 1, are also 1 in the binary representation of i. So, for instance, if N=3, then node 7 depends on all other nodes. Node 6 depends on nodes 4 and 2.

The problem is eliminating nodes. I can eliminate a node if no other nodes depend on it. No nodes depend on 7; so I can eliminate 7. After eliminating 7, I can eliminate 6, 5, and 3, etc. What I'd like is to find an efficient algorithm for listing all the possible unique elimination paths. (that is, 7-6-5 is the same as 7-5-6, so we only need to list one of the two). I have a dumb algorithm already, but I think there must be a better way.

I have three related questions:

1. Does this problem have a general name?
2. What's the best way to solve it?
3. Is there a general formula for the number of unique elimination paths?

Edit: I should note that a node cannot depend on itself, by definition.

Edit2: Let `S = {s_1, s_2, s_3,...,s_m}` be the set of all `m` valid elimination paths. `s_i` and `s_j` are "equivalent" (for my purposes) iff the two eliminations `s_i` and `s_j` would lead to the same graph after elimination. I suppose to be clearer I could say that what I want is the set of all unique *graphs* resulting from valid elimination steps.

Edit3: Note that elimination paths may be different lengths. For N=2, the 5 valid elimination paths are `(),(3),(3,2),(3,1),(3,2,1)`. For N=3, there are 19 unique paths.

Edit4: Re: my application - the application is in statistics. Given N factors, there are 2^N - 1 possible terms in statistical model (see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Analysis_of_variance#ANOVA_for_multiple_factors) that can contain the main effects (the factors alone) and various (2,3,... way) interactions between the factors. But an interaction can only be present in a model if all sub-interactions (or main effects) are present. For three factors `a`, `b`, and `c`, for example, the 3 way interaction `a:b:c` can only be in present if all the constituent two-way interactions (`a:b`, `a:c`, `b:c`) are present (and likewise for the two-ways). Thus, the model `a + b + c + a:b + a:b:c` would not be allowed. I'm looking for a quick way to generate all *valid* models.

Comment: What can be consider as unique? 5 and 6 actually are not similar if we look at their positions in graph.

Comment: Isn't the graph a [DAG](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Directed_acyclic_graph) and the algorithm similar to [topological sort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Topological_sort)?

Comment: Also, your requirements are a bit vague. If `7-6-5` and `7-5-6` are the same, why wouldn't (imaginary paths) `7-6-5-4-3-2-1` and `7-6-4-5-3-1-2` be the same?

Comment: @Shahbaz, no, because `7-6-4-5-3-1-2` is not an elimination path. You can't eliminate 4 before 5, because 5 depends on 4.

Comment: @PhamTrung, I mean that two eliminations paths are the same if they both leave the same graph after the elimination (assuming they are both valid eliminations).

Comment: @user1129889, that's why I said (imaginary paths). What I mean is, what keeps you from saying that two different permutations of `1` to `2^N-1` are the same?

Comment: @Shahbaz I think I understand what you mean now. See edit2.

Comment: I'm sorry, but it's still not clear to me. It still looks like you have only a single unique elimination path. For your example of `N=7`, can you name any path that is not equivalent to `7-6-5-4-3-2-1`? Perhaps if you could quickly draw a couple of graphs that would be more clear.

Comment: Ok I see your edit. So you are talking about _incomplete_ paths, not just complete elimination paths, right? Also, in your example with `N=2`, why are `(3,2)` and `(3,1)` different?

Comment: @Shahbaz, see edit3. Paths need not be of length 2^N-1; thus, `7-6`, a valid path, is not equivalent to `7-6-5-4-3-2-1`. They leave you with different graphs.

Comment: @Shahbaz, after `(3,1)` the remaining graph is only node 2, and `(3,2)` the remaining graph is only node 1. The two paths lead to different graphs, therefore they are not equivalent.

Comment: I understand now. Previously I was under the impression that you are comparing graphs topologically. I'll think about it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to @FalkHüffner's answer, I saw that what I wanted to do was equivalent to finding monotonic Boolean functions for N arguments. If you look at the figure on the Wikipedia page for Dedekind numbers (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dedekind_number) the figure expresses the problem graphically. There is an algorithm for generating monotonic Boolean functions (http://www.mathpages.com/home/kmath094.htm) and it is quite simple to construct.

For my purposes, I use the algorithm, then eliminate the first column and last row of the resulting binary arrays. Starting from the top row down, each row has a `1` in the `i`th column if one can eliminate the `i`th node.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

It seems easier to think about this in terms of sets: you are looking for families of subsets of {1, ..., N} such that for each set in the family also all its subsets are present. Each such family is determined by the inclusion-wise maximal sets, which must be overlapping. Families of pairwise overlapping sets are called [Sperner families](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sperner_family). So you are looking for Sperner families, plus the union of all the subsets in the family. Possibly known algorithms for enumerating Sperner families or antichains in general are useful; without knowing what you actually want to do with them, it's hard to tell.

Comment: The Dedekind numbers (3,6,20) do look like the number of paths + 1 for N=1, 2, and 3. Do it looks like the answer to (3) is probably "No".

Answer (score 0):

You can build a "heap", in which at depth `X` are all the nodes with `X` zeros in their binary representation.

Then, starting from the bottom layer, connect each item to a random parent at the layer above, until you get a single-component graph.

Note that this graph is a **tree**, i.e., each node except for the root has exactly one parent.

Then, traverse the tree (starting from the root) and count the total number of paths in it.

### UPDATE:

The method above is bad, because you cannot just pick a random parent for a given item - you have a limited number of items from which you can pick a "legal" parent... But I'm leaving this method here for other people to give their opinion (perhaps it is not "that bad").

In any case, why don't you take your graph, extract a spanning-tree (you can use Prim algorithm or Kruskal algorithm for finding a minimal-spanning-tree), and then count the number of paths in it?